# Integrating jmeter and splunk to azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-pipelines, performance-testing, splunk

how to run JMeter jmx test/script in Azure pipeline and integrate Splunk to the same pipeline and view reports or logs

I tried to create a pipeline and added repo but not sure about how to add JMeter and Splunk to the pipeline and monitor logs with Splunk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are multiple ways of running a JMeter test, the easiest is using [command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/script.jmx -l /path/to/result.jtl
   ```

   however you will need to ensure that JMeter is installed on the Azure runner machine so you might need to take some extra steps to get this done. Alternatively you can consider using [Azure Load Testing](https://6/2/2023) service
2. When it comes to Splunk it's not clear what exactly you want to monitor. If you want to check JMeter load generator health and other metrics like real-time parsing of the .jtl results file you will need to [install Splunk forwarder](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/9.0.4/Forwarder/Installanixuniversalforwarder) as well.

   If you 're already using Splunk to monitor the system under test and would like to have alerts in case if monitored metrics exceed defined thresholds - take a look at [Splunk Observability Cloud Events](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeremyh-splunk.splunk-events) integration

Comment: Thank you for the response , with Splunk we monitor memory and cpu utilisation , it shows in graphs .  Basically we do load test of micro services